# Unable to start systemd service of springboot application

Tags: ubuntu, spring-boot, systemd

I followed the [spring documentation for creating systemd service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) to create a startup script for my springboot app.

FYI: I have see [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5983) resolved issue on github which states the issue is a permission issue but does not work for me the jar has 755 permission.

Here is my service description:

```
[Unit]
Description=gs-spring-boot-0.1.0
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/deploy/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I try to enable the service like this:

```
sudo systemctl enable  gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.service
```

am getting this error:

```
update-rc.d: error: gs-spring-boot-0.1.0 Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
```

When I check the status this is the output: 
[image]

[image]

**Note: I am using ubuntu and the jar file has permission: 755**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry adding this to `build.gradle` was the solution:

```
bootRepackage { executable = true }
```

It makes the jar to be executable. i.e after adding this code you should be able to run the app with this command:

```
./app-name.jar
```